# How to make text clickable in wpf combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently my combobox is working properly although i would like that when users press the Text field of my combobox the dropdownmenu shows.

I could do this in code for example with an event such as MouseLeftButtonUp but this works poorly especially when pressing the mouse left button several times in a row on the title.

```
                <ComboBox Name="comboBox1" IsTextSearchEnabled="False"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True" DropDownClosed="OnDropDownClosed" Text="The title for my combobox" Margin="30,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  IsReadOnly="True">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="CheckBox1" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <CheckBox.Content>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="5" />
                                </CheckBox.Content>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: where was the event added to? what happens when mouse left button is pressed several times in a row?

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `GotFocus` or `GotKeyboardFocus` event like this:

```
private void comboBox1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!comboBox1.IsDropDownOpen)
        comboBox1.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

> This works but when pressing several times on the combobox the box wont open again propably because the focus has not changed

Handle the `Loaded` event for the `ComboBox` and hook up an event handler for the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` of the `TextBox` then:

```
private void comboBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
    TextBox textBox = cmb.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cmb) as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (!comboBox1.IsDropDownOpen)
                comboBox1.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but when pressing several times on the combobox the box wont open again propably because the focus has not changed